# c# I want to calculate a number in base 3

Tags: c#

I work for a university and we have session numbers that go like this:

```
YYYYs
```

Where `YYYY` is four digit *year* (e.g. `2017`, `2020` etc.) and `s` is a *semester* which can be `1, 2, 3` (`1` stands for *spring*, `2` is *summer* and `3` is *winter*). Some examples:

```
20171 spring semester in year 2017
20172 summer    -/-           2017 
20173 winter    -/-           2017 
20181 spring    -/-           2018
```

I want to implement semester **+** and **-** *arithmetics* (`+ 1` means *next* semester, `- 1` means *previous* one), e.g.

```
20171 + 1 == 20172 (adding 1 semester)           i.e. 2017 spring + 1 = 2017 summer
20171 - 1 == 20163 (subtracting 1 semester)      i.e. 2017 spring - 1 = 2016 winter
20171 + 3 == 20181 (adding 3 semesters - a year) i.e. 2017 spring + 3 = 2018 spring 
20173 + 8 == 20202 (adding 8 semesters)          i.e. 2017 winter + 8 = 2020 summer
```

Any idea ???

Comment: I've read this three times and have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: are you asking how to calculate the number of years from a given number of semesters? How many semester do you have in a year? if you know that answer simply divide the number of semester by it.  Please don't expect from us to write you the entire code that will compute this. StackOverflow does not work this way

Comment: just a tip: [modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) is a good start to approach this problem

Comment: Not going to write code for you, but have an input for the current year `Y` and the number of semesters to add `n`. Take the number of semesters to add, `n`, and divide by 3 (`n / 3`) which will give you an integer number of years (rounded down). Then add `n % 3` (number of semesters remaining after adding the years) to your semester number (e.g. the '2' in 2018-2), and if greater than 3, subtract 3 from the semester year and add another 1 to the year.

Comment: If you actually write some code and explain why it doesn't work you'll be amazed how much help you'll get compared to just asking for an answer.

Comment: it does not sound complex, but rather confusing. The problem is also not really complex. As for questions on StackOverflo, please read the [Asking Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you need to show some effort on your own to solve this problem, and describe in what problems you ran while solving it

Comment: Thx , Yeah, I know it's sound complex, we have 3 semesters per year. The session is made of the year and a number which represent the semester. C. Helling you are in the same track that I am, I have something like s = (s +y) % 3 if (s + y) > 3 for the semester. and year = year + (((s-(s%3))/3) for the year. I'm stuck when I want to remove a number, it doesn't wok all the time. I'll keep working ...

Comment: you can use the edit button below your post [or click here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47437745/edit) to add the information from your comment to your original post.

Comment: A simple way to approach this would be to convert the number into total number of semesters, e.g. 20171 = 2017*3 + 1, add or subtract the proper number of semesters, then convert it back into the form you're using via division/modulo

Comment: Thanks everyone, you put me, on the right track, I think I'll be fine from here, english is not my mother tongue so i'm sorry if I was unclear

Comment: @David Migneault: I've edited your question (format *explained*, examples *highlighted*, question *put*). Welcome on Stack Overflow

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *modular arithmetics*, e.g.

```
private static int AddSemester(int value, int shift) {
  int semester = (value % 10 - 1 + shift);

  int deltaYear = semester >= 0 
    ? semester / 3 
    : semester / 3 + (semester % 3 == 0 ? 0 : -1);

  int deltaSemester = semester - deltaYear * 3;

  return (value / 10 + deltaYear) * 10 + deltaSemester + 1;
}
```

Tests:

```
var tests = Enumerable
  .Range(-9, 19)
  .Select(shift => $"20173 + {shift,2} == {AddSemester(20173, shift)}");

Console.WriteLine(tests);
```

Outcome:

```
20173 + -9 == 20143
20173 + -8 == 20151
20173 + -7 == 20152
20173 + -6 == 20153
20173 + -5 == 20161
20173 + -4 == 20162
20173 + -3 == 20163
20173 + -2 == 20171
20173 + -1 == 20172
20173 +  0 == 20173
20173 +  1 == 20181
20173 +  2 == 20182
20173 +  3 == 20183
20173 +  4 == 20191
20173 +  5 == 20192
20173 +  6 == 20193
20173 +  7 == 20201
20173 +  8 == 20202 <- Test from the question
20173 +  9 == 20203
```

Comment: Look great, I'll test that, thank you

Comment: @Mong Zhu Thanks, it's done